# How to quit program, if fstream.open() failed in subfunction

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, quit

I try to open a file in a function in a class:

```
void openFile(){

    inputFile.open(inputFilename.c_str());

    if (inputFile.is_open()){
      inputFile.read(buffer, skipAtBegin);
    } else {
      cerr << "Cannot open file: " << inputFilename << endl;
      exitNow();
    }
}
```

In main() i would just return 1, but how can i do this in a sub-sub-function-class the best/simplest way??

Return 1 all steps up to main?

Use ecxeptions?

Any `exit()` commands?

Comment: Yes. [`std::exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit). For exactly this purpose.

Comment: Actually, yes. The exit(int) command. But I would suggest using exceptions, since they give you a chance to handle these kinds of errors.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend exiting in your `openFile` function. You should return some type of value, and handle that where `openFile` is called. Or use exceptions in the same fashion.

Comment: Coming back all the way up to `main` is tedious, but can allow to properly dispose of any critical resources you might be using. `exit` will be enough most of the time otherwise.

Comment: Throw an exception you catch near the top of your program stack. Display appropriate message and return from main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there are three Options:

1. Use exit. Quit the program.
2. Use exception. Throw exceptions, handles elsewhere.
3. Set global status variable. Set global status, and let other
   functions checkt the status and  handle it.

Hope someone would come up with other options.

Comment: thanks for your help at frist  #include <cstdlib> and exit(1); works fine, i will later add exceptions.